# DatePickers Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation

I am slightly new to this so pardon for any misleading info.

I have a class that contains two DatePickers elements, from where i should first select the first one and of course pick the dates, then the second one.

So i thought it can be done this way:

Search for the class and get a List datePickersList , then take the first web element(datepicker) and find another elements within that element, so my question is how do i look for another elements inside located one. If there is a better way to go proceed, kindly advice.

The link to the Date Pickers here -> https://www.opngo.com/en/parkings/340/parking-harlay-pont-neuf?service=booking

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write your xpath following way

```
//td[contains(@class, 'rdtDay') and text() = '26'][1]
```

It will return two element but you need to click first one
so i manage it following way

```
 List<WebElement> link = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'rdtDay') and text() = '26'][1]"));
    link.get(0).click();
```

I have input static date you can add condition to check available date and pass the value dynamically